# W/cr_Chrome: Bad URI on deeplinking

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking, install-referrer

I use a deeplink to pass parameters to my application on start, combined with an install referrer link if the application is not installed already.
The link is this one:

```
<a href='intent://www.myweb.com/guide?siteId=5682&theme=44&lang=fr#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.example;S.market_referrer=siteId%3D5682%26theme%3D44%26lang%3Dfr;end'>Click here</a>
```

Everything works well in all cases, anyway I can see this message in Android Monitor when I click on the link:

```
W/cr_Chrome: Bad URI 'intent://www.myweb.com/audioguide?siteId=5682&theme=44&lang=fr#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.example;S.market_referrer=siteId%3D5682%26theme%3D44%26lang%3Dfr;end'
```

What's wrong here?

deeplinking seems to be something very secret as Google only talks about their Campaign....

**Edit**
Intent filter

```
<application
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post the intent-filter defined in your app manifest?

Comment: @ZaqWiedmann see my edit but I gave up Google deeplinking as it seems that none of Google nor Apple manage it correctly. So I now use Branch.io.

Comment: no worries, posted an answer, guessing its not something that can be validated (accepted), but maybe it'll help someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: my knowledge is in deeplinking from the browser (intents, applinks, universal links) far less in app configuration.

The problem here is likely that you were missing the `<action>` and `<category>` fields. Also I *think* even for `http` you need a `<data>` section too, I could be wrong.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.myweb.com" android:path="/guide"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For future reference the case I ran into with

```
W/cr_Chrome: Bad URI
```

Had to do with `autoVerify` being set: `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">` which causes intents to be validated as "applinks". More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#request-verify